# Observable.forkJoin is not working

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs

I've instantiated two `Observable` objects:

```
const observable1 = new Observable.create(observer => observer.next(1)); 
const observable2 = new Observable.create(observer => observer.next(2));  
Observable.forkJoin([observable1, observable2]).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

The above `forkJoin()` is not working even though each of observable.subscribe() is working.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`forkJoin` waits for all input streams to complete before emitting a resulting value. Since you don't complete observables, it never emits anything. Also, you don't need `new` with `Observable.create` and you can import `forkJoin` directly - no need to use it on `Observable`. Change your implementation to this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const observable1 = Observable.create(observer => { observer.next(1); observer.complete() });
const observable2 = Observable.create(observer => { observer.next(2); observer.complete() });

forkJoin([observable1, observable2]).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

For a really great explanation of combination operators, including `forkJoin` read:

- [Learn to combine RxJs sequences with super intuitive interactive diagrams](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511)

and [here's the link](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/fork-join) directly to the explanation of forkJoin operator.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, just finished writing it :). My goal was to get as visually comprehensive as possible with the flow digrams